# Difference of array, result is 1 or undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, difference

`Array a = [1,2,3,4,5,5]`

`Array b = [1,2,3,5]`

`c = a - b`

which should return `c = [4]` (5 is repeated twice but I dont want it in the output)
Now here is my code:

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
  var array = [];
  var diff = [];
  for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
    array[a[i]] = true;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i<b.length; i++) {
    if (array[b[i]]) {
      delete array[b[i]];
    }
    else {
      array[b[i]] = true;
    }

    for (var k in array) {
      return diff.push(k);
    }

  }

}
Test.describe("Sample tests", function() {
  Test.it("Should pass Sample tests", function() {
    Test.assertDeepEquals(arrayDiff([], [4,5]), [], "a was [], b was [4,5]");
    Test.assertDeepEquals(arrayDiff([3,4], [3]), [4], "a was [3,4], b was [3]");
    Test.assertDeepEquals(arrayDiff([1,8,2], []), [1,8,2], "a was [1,8,2], b was []");
  });
});
```

but it returns weird stuff. Can you please explain why it returns 1 and how do I fix it? This is the console.log output:

```
a was [], b was [4,5] - Expected: [], instead got: 1
a was [3,4], b was [3] - Expected: [4], instead got: 1
a was [1,8,2], b was [] - Expected: [1, 8, 2], instead got: undefined


Unhandled rejection TestError: a was [], b was [4,5] - Expected: [], instead got: 1
```

Can you please help me fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are couple of problems in your code

1. 3rd for loop that is nested inside the 2nd for loop should not be nested inside the 2nd loop.
2. `.push()` method adds a new item in the array and returns the length of the array after adding the new item. Instead of returning the return value  of push function, you need to return `diff` array.

Here's the fixed code

```js
const a = [1,2,3,4,5,5];
const b = [1,2,3,5];

function arrayDiff(a, b) {
  var array = [];
  var diff = [];
  for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
    array[a[i]] = true;
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i<b.length; i++) {
    if (array[b[i]]) {
      delete array[b[i]];
    }
    else {
      array[b[i]] = true;
    }
  }
    
  for (var k in array) {
      diff.push(Number(k));
  }
  
  return diff;
  
}

console.log(arrayDiff(a, b));
```

#### Edit

As per your comments, if `a = []` and `b = [1, 2]` then output should be `[]` and for `a = [1, 8, 2]` and `b = []`, output should be `[1, 8 ,2]`.

This isn't possible with your code as you are finding the difference based on array indexes and boolean values.

You can get the desired output by filtering the array `a` and checking if the current element in array `a` exists in array `b` or not.

```js
let a = [1, 8 ,2];
let b = [];

function arrayDiff(a, b) {
  return a.filter(n => !b.includes(n));
}

console.log(arrayDiff(a, b));
```

Comment: It returns it as a string, What do i do to make it return a number. Also there were some errors when I tried your code:
```

a was [], b was [4,5] - Expected: [], instead got: ['4', '5']
a was [3,4], b was [3] - Expected: [4], instead got: ['4']
a was [1,8,2], b was [] - Expected: [1, 8, 2], instead got: ['1', '2', '8']```

Comment: change `diff.push(k);` to `diff.push(Number(k));`

Comment: Try ```a = []``` ,``` b = [1,2]```. It returns ```[1,2]. If we change ```array[b[i]]``` to ```array[a[i]]``` in the else statement, it returns ```[NaN]```. Also try wirh ```a = [1,8,2]``` ```b = []```, it returns ```[1,2,8]```

Comment: i am not sure what you are trying to say. What else should it return when `a = []` and `b = [1. 2]` ?

Comment: It should return ```c = a - b``` so ```[] - [1,2]``` should return [], ```[1,8,2]-[]``` should return ```[1,8,2]``` instead it returns ```[1,2,8]```

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. It may need some modification to make it simple.

```
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
  return a.filter((aItem) => b.indexOf(aItem) === -1);
}
```

Comment: Can u please explain how it works? I am not familiar with ```=>```

Comment: `(params) => exp` means `function(params) { return exp; }`.
It is called arrow function

Comment: `filter` function of array take a function as its parameter.
Parameter function must return `true` or `false`.
So `filter` function returns new array which match the condition.

Comment: Okay, i get it. It looks like babel, i used it a little but i have no experience with it.

Comment: Thank you for your help tho

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the array.

```js
function arrayDiff(a, b) {
    const setB = new Set(b);
    return a.filter(v => !setB.has(v));
}

console.log(arrayDiff([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5]));
```

Comment: It works but i need to run it using a function like the code i have created above